# bibLatex alphabetic style, maximal authors alphabetic style

Tags: biblatex, author-number

I use biblatex with the biber backend and the alphabetic style. When I cite a paper which is written by many authors (eg. Aname Bname Cname Dname) the BibTex entry will look like this:

```
[Ana+97]
```

but I'd like to have

```
[ABCD97]
```

I tried the 'maxauthors' or 'maxbibnames' option to adjust this behavior but it didn't have any effect. I import the biblatex package with:

```
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=alphabetic,
  maxauthors=99,
  maxbibnames=99,
  sortlocale=de_DE,
  natbib=true,
  url=false, 
  doi=true,
  eprint=false
]{biblatex}
```